# How to track and show element position in input?

Tags: javascript

I have some dragging elements on my page:

```
<h1 id="text1" class="drag" style="top:446.5px; left: 590.5px;">Title</h1>
<img id="img1" src="" data-resize="true" data-src="" class="drag" style="top:446.5px; left: 590.5px;">
```

I used this code to make them dragable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
var positions = JSON.parse(localStorage.positions || "{}");
$(function () {
    var d = $("[class=draggable]").attr("class", function (i) {
        return "draggable_" + i
    })
    $.each(positions, function (id, pos) {
        $("#" + id).css(pos)
    })

    d.draggable({
        scroll: false,
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            positions[this.id] = ui.position
            localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

It works, when element has only one class name. If there is a class like "draggable color fill" it doesnt work.

How to make it possible to use multiply class names? Thank you for help.

Comment: Yes it is. May look into Draggabillys sourcecode

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use the offsetHeight and offsetWidth properties.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetheight.asp